# How to enable 'install unknown apps' on Samsung mobile device?

Tags: samsung, security, android-10

My Samsung device is running on **Android 10, One UI 2.0**. I want to install apps using apk file via non-official platforms (the app is not published on Google Play, Galaxy Store). But it won't let me.

*Settings > Biometrics and security > Install unknown apps*,

All the listed apps there (e.g. Google Chrome, File Manager) are disabled by default and greyed out, stating:

> Installing apps from this source may put your phone and data at risk.

[image: IMG:]

I googled a little, [this forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/903078-install-unknown-apps-all-disabled-greyed-out.html) discussed about the exactly same problem I am facing. One user there said that disabling admin apps can help. I went to

*Settings > Biometrics and security > Other security settings > Device admin apps*,

I see 5 listed apps (I think most Samsung device is sharing the same, except the Outlook's one because I installed Outlook).

[image: IMG:]

I click into one, this shows up and *'deactivate'* is greyed out as well. None of them can be deactivated.

[image: IMG:]

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this. As previously when I was using Huawei device, I had no issue like this, system won't stop me from enable it. As far as I can tell from Google results, there are Samsung device users facing the **exactly** same issue. Official forum and YouTube are useless, solution given is just tell you where to find the settings, or just demonstrate you how to enable it without issue like this meanwhile under comment section people complaint about this issue, there was no solution. Send help. I apologize in advance if I posted the wrong question on the wrong forum category.

Comment: One UI 2.0 user, but rooted. Is your phone's work profile administrated by your employer, by chance?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (question was migrated but OP didn't join the site and the existing answers has no votes). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

What worked 4 me once was sending the .apk file from an email app n opening it up there. Not sure why or how that happened